# How to save the output from `each` method

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, iteration, each

Trying to write a method that will take a string and return the pig-latin version of it. The single-word version works fine, but when I give it `"eat pies"`, it returns `"eat pies"` and not `"eatay iespay"` like it should. Here's the code:

```
def translate(string)
  x = string
  if x.split.count > 1 
    splitskies = x.split
    splitskies.each do |w|
      if w[0].match(/[aeiou]/)
        w = w + "ay"
      elsif w[0] !~ (/[aeiou]/) && w[1] !~ (/[aeiou]/)
        w = w[2..-1] + w[0..1] + "ay"
      elsif w[0] !~ (/[aeiou]/)
        w = w[1..-1] + w[0] + 'ay'
      end
    return splitskies.join(' ')
   end
  else
    if x[0].match(/[aeiou]/)
      x = x + "ay"
    elsif x[0] !~ (/[aeiou]/) && x[1] !~ (/[aeiou]/)
      x[2..-1] + x[0..1] + "ay"
    elsif x[0] !~ (/[aeiou]/)
      l = x.slice!(0)
      x = x + l + "ay"
    end
  end
end
```

Can you also explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497422/can-you-append-to-specific-elements-in-an-array-based-on-if-statement-conditions

Comment: Thanks for the link @pjs ! I finally figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this question from? I've seen it a few times.

Your code isn't working because you aren't modifying `splitskies`, just messing with a copy of each word in it.

I think this is what you're looking for. It basically does the same as yours, but doesn't use a separate `if` for each leading consonant: it just removes *all* leading consonants and puts them at the end, followed by `ay`. There's no need to check how many words there are in the phrase as you can `join` a single-element list just fine.

```
def translate(phrase)
  phrase.split.map do |word|
    word.gsub('qu', 'q') =~ /^([^aeiou]*)(.*)/
    ($2 + $1 + 'ay').gsub('q', 'qu')
  end.join ' '
end

puts pig('eat pie')
```

**output**

```
eatay iepay
```

Comment: The tutorial comes from here:  http://testfirst.org/learn_ruby  Your code is WAY shorter than mine and works for most cases, can you explain how it works? If the word contains a vowel (maybe I don't understand the regex completely), what are the $2 and $1? This ended up being my solution:  https://gist.github.com/Sp33k3rph433k/6611873

Answer (score 1):

The "each" method is used for its side effects - it returns the original object that you passed to it. Try it in IRB:

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.each {|elem| elem ** 2}
p array
[1,2,3]
```

Try using "map" instead. That method will return a modified object.

```
array = [1,2,3]
array.map {|elem| elem ** 2}
p array
[1,4,9]
```

Comment: That is immensely helpful and I appreciate the input. Still getting started, but map did end up working!